# Can i store java returned hashmap in robot framework variable?

Tags: java, robotframework

I created a robot framework keyword in java that returns a hashmap

```
public HashMap<String, Object> createMap(String data) {

    HashMap<String, Object> session = new HashMap<String,Object>();
     //do something

    return session;
}
```

I would like to call this keyword in a robot framework test case and store the map in a robot framework variable and access it's values later.

I tried to use dictionary but it didn't seem to work. Can someone show me how to do it? Can it be done?

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out. This works for robot framework 2.8.7

I can just do:

```
${session}= | Create Map
```

and the hashmap will be stored in the ${session} variable. Use the dictionary keywords from robot framework BuiltIn/Collection library to access the key value pairs.